# android.widget.Gallery inside a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to place a android.widget.Gallery inside a view pager at the bottom.  The user will read and scroll all the way to the bottom and than see more pictures to view inside the Gallery at the bottom.  I want to be able to scroll horizontally through the Gallery w/o switching pages. So when the user is interacting with the Gallery, I don't want the horizontal swipe of the ViewPager to take over and switch pages.  How can this be done?

Comment: I know that Gallery is deprecated but it still does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend horizontal scrolling item in a horizontal scrolling viewpager.

To try this you have a couple options, lots of items: 1.) search horizontal list view.  less items: 2.) horizontal scrollview.  I guess option 3.) use gallery even though depreciated.

However, I encourage you to try it, it just doesn't work very well with two items scrolling the same way.

For the same reason it's not a good idea to have a vertical scroll inside another vertical scroll.

About the only way this can work is if you give the user a separate full screen non-horizontally scrolling window with your horizontally scrolling item.

Comment: I don't recommend it either but its a requirement for my app, and I don't make the rules, I implement them.